# In Excel 2016, how do I validate the data entered in a column conditioning it on what a value is on another sheet in the same workbook?

Tags: excel, validation

The first sheet in my workbook lists different accounts that are associated with specific process types--there are up to six different process types (PT01, PT02, PT03, etc), and the accounts associated with a specific process type cannot be associated with a different process type.  The accounts for a specific process type are a subset of a much larger account list that are possible for that process type.  These are entered by a customer, specific to their company.
On a different sheet in my workbook, I have labels, each of which must be associated with an account; that account MUST come from one of the accounts listed on my first sheet, for process type PT04.
How do I validate that the Accounts able to be selected for associating with the labels can only be from process type PT04, in my list of accounts?

[image: Process Type-Account List]

[image: Label-Account List]

Comment: As an FYI, I have the Labels on a separate worksheet to be able to run macros that I would not be able to do, if there was just a Label column on the Accounts List sheet and no separate sheet for Labels.